# symfony doctrine casts boolean to integer

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I'm migrating symfony2 application from mariaDB to postgres. Weird error at saving an entity:
seems like query looks like:

1. update an entity at sometable
2. select * from sometable

> "START TRANSACTION"

> UPDATE Partner SET is_active = ? WHERE id = ? array(2) { [0]=> bool(true) [1]=> int(1) }

> SELECT (literally all) FROM Partner p0_ WHERE p0_.is_active = 1 AND p0_.manager_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY p0_.manager_id ORDER BY sclr_37 ASC LIMIT 1

> "ROLLBACK"

and it fails with 1 being not equal to boolean true

two major questions here: "why two queries" and "how to prevent autoconverting true to 1 in select query"

Answer (score 0):

closing for some hardcoded listener which executed second query.
answering both questions and sorry for bother.